# Read/Output JSON with PHP from within a class and function

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, class, pdo

I normally get all JSON data using Jquery however I currently need to do it using only PHP.

Essentially this is how I normally get and output it with Jquery: (Snippet, not whole code)

```
$.post('getdata.php', {uid:uid} , function(data){
    if(data){   
    $.each(data, function(key, data) {
    $('#div #span-'+key).html(data);
    });

}

} , 'json')
```

Where uid is the value passed to php for use in querying the database.

And this is the php back end: (Again just a snippet of the JSON section)

```
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $ret["ID"]       = $row['id'];
    $ret["username"] = $row['username'];
    $ret["email"]    = $row['email'];
    $ret["age"]      = $row['age'];
    echo json_encode($ret);
}
```

And obviously on the output page along with jquery I initiate the class and function:

```
$class = new retrieveData();
$class->userDetails();
```

Then to output the individual parts of the array where I want I would create a span with the same unique key for the particular array part as set out in jquery.

How would I go about converting the jquery part of this into PHP?

Comment: What do you mean?  What are you wanting the PHP to do?  Modify contents of an HTML page store in a string?  A page that you are currently creating? etc?

Comment: your json generation in php is incorrect. you're generating multiple INDEPENDENT json snippets. this is totally wrong. you need to fetch your query data into an array, then encode the entire array.

Comment: I want to get the entire array from the PHP function and then call different parts of the array to display on different parts of the page. I dont want the entire array to be displayed in one go.

E.g: Display the username on the left hand side of the page, and than maybe display the email part of the array in a sidebar... etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if im understanding you you just want to rework the whole ajax side to sending off a request from the server:

```
$ch = curl_init($theUrlThatReturnsTheData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('uid' => $uid));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
$jsonData = curl_exec($ch);

$data = json_decode($jsonData);
```

Now do whatever it is you need to do with json... assuming from your jquery fragment thats
something like this:

```
<div id="<?php echo $uid ?>">
   <?php foreach($data as $key => $value): ?>
       <span id="span-<?php echo $key ?>">
         <?php echo $value ?>
       </span>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.
I half had it done but wasnt including the "echo $key" part.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is written in JavaScript and runs on the user's browser while PHP runs only on the server. You cannot convert something that runs on the browser to something that runs on the server. In other words, you cannot use AJAX functions such as `post`

Read [this article](http://www.virtualshowrooms.co.za/articlepage.php?cp=101)

Comment: ... yes you can. you can use `curl` for 'post', and you can use PHP to generate JS which is sent to the browser.  And depending on the functionality, a lot of code can be ported to other languages.

Comment: Ric, That script works fine. It runs through a controller file that allows the PHP to be returned without refreshing the page.
The question I am asking though, is how to actually re-write that Jquery script into a PHP script.

Comment: @Jon I assume he's trying to convert AJAX based on his snippet. I know you can use `curl` to perform server-side requests.

Comment: @Ric Look at the accepted answer ^^  What he wanted was exactly `curl`, just trying to get the json object from PHP instead of JS. ^^

Comment: @Jon Nice, I would not have thought that was what he wanted. I won't question it.